# after changing from html to php my javascript wont work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a contact page that has a form that uses a js function to validate the user input and then highlights the missing/wrong fields. However, after implementing the php function to mail and changing the format from html to php my form simply doesn't validate anymore, it goes straight the sendmail.php file.

here is my form format :

```
<form name="form" method ="post" onsubmit="return validate();" action="sendmail.php">
```

my js function :

```
function validate(){
var email = document.querySelector('#email').value;
var msg = document.querySelector('#mensagem').value;
var name = document.querySelector('#name').value;
var filter_name = /^[a-z\u00C0-\u00ff A-Z]+$/;                    
var filter_mail = /^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+\.)[a-zA-Z-0-9]{2}/;
    if(!filter_name.test(name)){
    $('#name').css("background","rgb(215, 237, 192)");
    return false;
    }
    if(!filter_mail.test(email)){

    $('#email').css("background","rgb(215, 237, 192)");
    return false;
    }

    return true;
    };

var nameTxtField = document.querySelector('#name');
var emailTxtField = document.querySelector('#email');

nomeTxtField.addEventListener('focus',function(){
this.style.background = 'white';
});

emailTxtField.addEventListener('focus',function(){
this.style.background = 'white';
});
```

and my sendmail.php file does that :

```
<?php 
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$uf=$_POST['uf'];
$city=$_POST['cidade'];
$profe=$_POST['prof'];
$mensg =$_POST['msg'];
$to = "email@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact";
$msg = "<strong>Name:</strong>$name <br /> <strong>Email:</strong>$email<br /><strong>Uf:</strong>$uf<br /><strong>CiTY:</strong>$cidade<br /><strong>ProfE:</strong>$profe<br /><strong>Mensg:</strong>$mensg<br />";
$header = "MIME-VERSION: 1.0\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
$header .= "From: $email\n";

function spamcheck($email)
  {

 $email=filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

  if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
    return TRUE;
    }
  else
    {
    return FALSE;
    }
  }

  if(spamcheck == true){
mail($to,$subject,$mensg<,$header);
}

?>
```

I'm also using the
`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` to reference jquery in all my files and all my ids and functions are working just fine. For example i have a working html file with all the code, but when i change its extension to .php it automatically stops validating but sends the email .

Does anyone have an idea?
ps: If you guys find any inconsistence with the ids, it was just because i had to translate them to english before posting, so it is just a typo.

Comment: look for error in console or firebug console

Comment: Hey! I just checked that and it is saying that i cannot get the reference to null (from my text field that I want to change the color).

Comment: Can u show us the JavaScript code where u r getting that error & also the HTML part to which u r pointing by that JavaScript.

Comment: [SOLVED]Hey everyone, sorry for the long question. I figured out that the error was actually on my ids. I'll leave my question here so if anyone needs a js validation code and php email sending example.

Answer (score 0):

actually it validates but as u have given action with sendmail.php, it gives priority and redirects it before validation completes,

-i would suggest you to use either ajax.
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

or block your submition of page on failing of validation
  for example you can check for all validations and on success you can use 
redirect method of php or javascript

Comment: After matching correctly the ids my JS does block sending the form if there is a wrong required field

Comment: just remove that action attribute
and can use this

function validate(){
/*your code*/
var setFlag=true;
    if(!filter_name.test(name)){
    $('#name').css("background","rgb(215, 237, 192)"); setFlag=false;
    //return false;
    }
    if(!filter_mail.test(email)){

    $('#email').css("background","rgb(215, 237, 192)"); setFlag=false;
    return false;
    }
if(setflag){window.location.replace("http://yourhome/sendmail.php");}
    //return true;
    };

Comment: think it like : keep priority for a form to perform an action, either it validates or submits, in your case it was prioritizing action attribute so block it till it validation is successfull

Comment: So the action of going to the php file that has the emailing script would be called inside the js function? What if the user deactivates Js on the browser? My form would be completely crashed (nor validating nor emailing) right?

Comment: if you are thinking like-wise think that wat if user has disable js, he would not validate anything straight away redirect and your next processing thing will b filled with crap...

Comment: so think that validation is important,
even u want such thing dont validate it on js side vaildate it on server side..
php provides you iwth server side validation too.. no need of js validations..

Comment: What about my style changes on the page? Since my js validates and changes the textfield background, what would be a good approach to validate on the server side and changing the style accordingly to the specific wrong field?

Comment: recommended way from my side is ajax,
for more help visit this:
http://brian.staruk.me/php/2013/sample-jquery-php-ajax-script/
so on success response you can maintain all css very well here.
on the requested page.php you can write somthing like:

if($validation==true){
//success case
php redirect to sendemail.php
}else{
jsonencode(sendArrayOferrormessage)
}

the other ways are quit lengthy